# Why can I not access 'passport' fields in session store JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, session

I've got a node application that uses express, socket.io 1.0 and passport. When a user auths through passport-twitter I store their information in a session store using the below code;

```
    var passportSocketIo = require("passport.socketio");
    var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore
           ,sessionStore = new MemoryStore();

    io.set('authorization', passportSocketIo.authorize({
          cookieParser: express.cookieParser,
          key:         'express.sid',
          secret:      'secret',
          store:       sessionStore
    }));
```

I then use the following for my socket.io connection handler;

```
    io.on("connection", function(client){   
        console.log(sessionStore.sessions[client.request.sessionID]);
    });
```

This returns all the session data for the client with that ID in this format;

```
{
    "cookie": {
        "originalMaxAge": null,
        "expires": null,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "path": "/"
    },
    "passport": {
        "user": {
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
            [...],
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that if I tried to access "passport" from the structure, the result is always undefined. I tried the following (both with and without the `.` before "passport");

- sessionStore.sessions[client.request.sessionID].[passport]
- sessionStore.sessions[client.request.sessionID].["passport"]
- sessionStore.sessions[client.request.sessionID].passport
- sessionStore.sessions[client.request.sessionID]."passport"

Unfortunately these return as undefined. I'm really just trying to get the `passport.user.id` field value out of that structure so I can perform some DB lookup (e.g. user group, user privacy settings, etc) and so I can ensure I emit the correct DB data back to the client.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it further, it appears that passing it through `JSON.parse()` was the correct method to use;

```
var jsobj = JSON.parse(sessionStore.sessions[client.request.sessionID]);
console.log(jsobj.passport.user.id);
```

or for a single line solution;

```
console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStore.sessions[client.request.sessionID]).passport.user.id);
```